# Python Regex don't match if word in line

Tags: python, regex, ansible

I'm currently creating an Ansible play which includes adding a specific port range to CSF's config file.

The string in the file appears as follows:

```
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2077,2078,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,20960"
```

I need a regex that will match the line starting with 'TCP_IN = ' only **IF** it does not contain the port range already. E.g. this should match:

```
portrange = 3000:5000

TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2077,2078,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,20960"
```

But this should not match:

```
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2077,2078,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,20960,3000:5000"
```

And the same being true if the port range appears at the beginning or in the middle of the string.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: Are the numbers supposed to be on the same line, or on the next line?

Comment: @jonrsharpe -> I'm using the 'lineinfile' module from Ansible which needs a regex and uses Python regex. Basically, if 3000:5000 doesn't exist, it must add it to the line. If it does exist, it mustn't find that line. So it's only adding it when it doesn't exist.

Comment: @tobias_k: it is one line, just doesn't fit in the text. sorry.

Comment: @tobias_k: Can't use `:` as there could be other ranges specified in the string that I don't want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this negative lookahead based regex:

```
\bTCP_IN\s+=\s+"(?![\d,:]*?\b3000:5000\b)[\d,:]+"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN7xJ7/1)

In python use:

```
regex = re.compile(ur'\bTCP_IN\s+=\s+"(?![\d,:]*?\b3000:5000\b)[\d,:]+"')
```

Regex doesn't do any validation of ports, it just allows a digit OR comma or colon in input.

Comment: Just tested this and can confirm it works as it should. If anyone is curious, this is the adapted line as I have it in my code. `lineinfile: dest=/etc/csf/csf.conf state=present regexp='\bTCP_IN\s+=\s+"((?![\d,:]*?\b{{ newRange }}\b)[\d,:]+)' line='TCP_IN = "\1,{{ newRange }}"' backrefs=yes backup=yes`